# Find all visible elements using Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to the count of find all visible elements under a container using Protractor

```
function getVisibleDivs(driver) { 
  var links = driver.findElements(by.css("#MainContent div")); 
  return protractor.promise.filter(links, function(link) { 
    link.isDisplayed(); 
   })
  .then(function(visibleLinks) {
      return visibleLinks; 
    }); 
}

element.all(getVisibleDivs).then(function (items) {
        console.log(items.length);
});
```

I always get the count as 0 though I have manually checked that the elements are present. Any pointers for debugging this much appreciated.

**UPDATE** Some sample html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="MainContent">
            <div class="header">
                Header
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Content
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar" style="display:none">
                Sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                Footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems your selector is wrong. your selector is searching for an element with the id #MainContent followed by a div element. would you show some html?

Comment: @nilsK: The actual HTML is quite complex. I have put some sample HTML in the question on which I could reproduce the issue. Thanks

Comment: sorry for the late reply. try the following: var main = driver.findElement(by.id('#MainContent')); main.findElements(by.tagName('div')).then(function(divArr) {//...});
Problem here, divArr will contain ALL div elements found inside MainConent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter function does not return anything, so add 'return' to link.isDisplayed():

```
function getVisibleDivs(driver) { 
  var links = driver.findElements(by.css("#MainContent div")); 
  return protractor.promise.filter(links, function(link) { 
    return link.isDisplayed(); 
   })
  .then(function(visibleLinks) {
      return visibleLinks; 
    }); 
}

element.all(getVisibleDivs).then(function (items) {
        console.log(items.length);
});
```

Answer (score 12):

There is no need to use `protractor.promise` directly. Protractor exposes functional programming functions like [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) on [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) - the result of `element.all()`.

Here is how to use it:

```
var visibleDivs = $$("#MainContent div").filter(function(link) { 
    return link.isDisplayed();
});

expect(visibleDivs.count()).toEqual(3);
```